# How to create a shortcut to maximize horizontally a window in KDE Plasma?

Tags: linux, kde

"*Provided your window is not already maximized, clicking on the maximize button with the right mouse button will maximize it horizontally*"
How to create a shortcut for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I founded the answer by myself on http://ubuntuforums.org/:
**Alt+F2 and type "systemsettings" then click on "Shortcuts and Gestures". The window management shortcuts are under "Global Keyboard shortcuts", then select "Kwin" from the drop-down menu.**

Link to original thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1754809